# Difference between Supervisor MaxTries and Attempts

Tags: php, laravel, unix, supervisord

I am using **Supervisor** to run jobs at **Laravel Queues**

I have specified **$tries=1** at *job level* in laravel.

Still Supervisor is applying multiple attempts to run the job

Why such behaviour ?

As per my understanding, Supervisor should be trying to attempt this job, at max to the $tries count mentioned.

[image: Why Attempts exceeding MaxTries]

Comment: Did you override the value on your job class?

Comment: @Jerodev Yes.. I speceified that on $tries variable in job class